# Dereference C: drive c# asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, webforms, sqlconnection

I want my code to only grab my sql script from the relative path starting from my project folder not from the absolute path. I'm using web forms and plan on publishing this code on a server so I need to dereference by paths.

CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory:

```
"C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\folder_name\\project_name\\project_name\\"
```

What it looks like when it grabbing the file:

```
"C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\folder_name\\project_name\\project_name\\sql_script"
```

What I want it to look like:

```
"project_name\\sql_script"
```

or something similar

```
            using (SqlConnection mer = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = server_address; Initial Catalog = server_name; Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {
                {
                    mer.Open();
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~/mergeSQL.sql");
                    string mergeScript = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( path);
                    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> commandStrings = Regex.Split(mergeScript, @"^\s*GO\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    foreach (string commandString in commandStrings)
                    {
                        if (commandString.Trim() != "")
                        {
                            using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, mer))
                            {
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            Label2.Text = "Query merged";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `DirectoryInfo` class to get the parent folder, and the parent of the parent folder and so on. And then concatenate both results. Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-7.0

Comment: You can also `Split("\\", path)` the path and with the resulting array, get the **N**th and **N**th-1 items so that you can concatenate them.

Comment: @RivoR. Would I use the Spilt() command after path or mergeScript?

Comment: @RivoR. Also I'm not trying to concatenate. Realistically I only want the variable to store "\\sql_script"

Comment: You can use `Split("\\", path)` after when you grab the path `"C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\folder_name\\project_name\\project_name\\sql_script"
`.

Comment: @RivoR. can't use split because I do not have a string []

Answer (score 1):

windows file names are well, just a full path string.

So, if you have a folder in your web site, say:

```
 sql_scripts
```

Then for web based, they are automatic

```
 http:yourwebsite/sql_scripts/mysql.txt
```

however, of course that folder would not be public.

And keep in mind the DIFFERENCE between markup, web based url's and code behind.

Code behind STILL = plain jane full windows path names.

So, in code you can get the base site and path - regardless of where or what server the project is running.

```
 string MyFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/sql_scripts/myfile.txt")
```

The above will return a FULL qualified full windows path name.

While the web site url's might be restricted, code behind is NOT and 100% ignores the web site security settings.

So, while the above is not a relative path name, you don't care, since it will be translated into a full legal path name, which as I noted all code behind is to use (a simple plane jane full qualified windows path name).

So,

```
web based markup = path name from and relative to web root
code behind = always a full legal path name to file.
```

Thus, you can get that legal file name + full path by using Server.MapPath